# Running Debian jessie, missing some packages

Tags: debian, package-management

I want to install [gajim](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gajim) and [virtualbox-fuse](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=virtualbox-fuse) in Debian jessie but the repository isn't offering me these. What's the correct approach on this?
Backports, wheezy or repositories from oracle/gajim?

Virtualbox seems even more complicated since virtualbox is in jessie but virtualbox-fuse is not. And virtualbox-fuse depends on virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *correct* solution for non-existing packages, but only more or less elegant solutions.

virtualbox-fuse has been dropped, since it is incompatible with the current virtualbox version (see the [changelog of Debian's virtualbox package](http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs/contrib/v/virtualbox/unstable_changelog)).

So if you need it, you need to forward-port the whole virtualbox packages from wheezy (which includes virtualbox-fuse). Forward-porting works like back-porting.

As jessie is similar to unstable, you can try to install the current gajim package from unstable without updating other packages.

But this gajim version has [a grave bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725196) which could be the reason why it has been temporarily removed from jessie / did not migrate to it. As soon as the bug is fixed, it will migrate automatically to jessie. Helping the maintainer fixing the bug can speed this up.

So forward-port it from wheezy can be also a good solution.

If offered, using packages from non-official repositories / repositories from related distribution can also be a solution.
Compiling software by yourself should work, but is in general not easy.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess im going to simply fire up the vm and copy the files out the normal way. 

About the forward port stuff, do i need to add apt pinning rules or can i just add the repositories ?

Comment: @iluvdebian For forward/backporting you need to rebuild the packages so that they binaries depend on the library versions you have installed. With apt-pinning you can mix packages from different repositories (unstable, testing, stable) which does not work always. I suggest you to first try the apt-pinning method and if it does not work (because of unsolvable conflicts between packages), you can still try to forward/backport which is more complicated.